# Yii2 Validate Only Create Action

Tags: yii2

Now in my model there is a validation rule like this

```
 [['title'], 'required'],
```

But it validate both on create and update action.
What I want to do is just validate on create action only.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its called 'scenarios': http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios

in model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['title', 'required', 'on' => 'create']
    ];
}
```

in controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
     $model = new Item();
     $model->scenario = 'create';
     ...
}
```

You'd better define scenario as a constant though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use scenarios in yii 2 to achieve this. 'on'=>'create' scenarios can be used here in model.

```
[['title'], 'required','on'=>'create'],
```

and in controller you have to call that scenraio.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
     $model = new Student();
     $model->scenario = 'create';
     ...
}
```

There is a concept of custom scenraio also which provides better validations rules. 
Reference :- [custom scenarios in yii 2](https://www.mycodingtutorials.com/?p=385)